# Haskell construct analogous to Rust trait objects

Tags: haskell

Haskell supports *type classes*, like equality:

```hs
class Eq a where 
  (==)                  :: a -> a -> Bool
```

Rust does the same with *type traits*:

```rust
pub trait Draw {
    fn draw(&self);
}
```

Now, it's possible to declare in Haskell a list whose elements must belong to the equality type class: `Eq a => [a]` (I believe `a` is called a *constrained type* in Haskell). However, the elements of the list still must all be the same type! Say, all `Integer` or all `Float` or something. In Rust, however, one can have a list (a vector) of values where each implements a given trait but they are not necessarily the same concrete type: `Vec<Box<dyn Draw>>`. Is there a way to do the same in Haskell? Like, I want a list of values but all I care about is that each belong to some type class but not necessarily the same concrete type.

Comment: Yes, and it's a very good question. But it's also an excellent demonstration of how different paradigms interact. I've used both Rust and Haskell extensively. I use `dyn` trait objects in Rust fairly frequently, and I almost never use existentials in Haskell. It's just a difference in the way the language nudges you and the way you solve problems in different languages.

Comment: Note that with Haskell `Eq` (I don't know how Rust does equality checks), having a list of objects of different types that all implement `Eq` would be entirely useless. That's because `(==) :: a -> a -> Bool` requires two objects **known** to be of the same type for the call to even typecheck. Only an interface that can do interesting things with a single object makes much sense to use with this capability.

Comment: @Ben I don't really think that's true. For example, `data ExContainer where EC :: Num a => IntMap a -> ExContainer` seems like it could plausibly use binary operators like `(+)` and `(*)` (or even `(==)` if you added `Eq`) nontrivially, even though the `a` is existentially quantified.

Comment: @DanielWagner True, although there the "interface" you get out of the existential is that it is specifically an `IntMap` of some unknown `a` that implements `Num`, and one could argue that that is an example of an interface that lets you do interesting things with a single value (being the `IntMap a` as a whole, which of course can containmultiple `a`s). A list of your `ExContainer`, as the OP was thinking about, would have every element in the list need to contain an `IntMap` (just for varying `a`), and you couldn't use the instances across values from the two different maps.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Haskell, you can use existential types to express "some unknown type of this typeclass". (In older versions of GHC, you will need a few standard extensions on.)

```
class Draw a where
   -- whatever the methods are

data SomeDraw where
   SD :: Draw a => a -> SomeDraw

type MyList = [SomeDraw]
```

However, note that this is often overkill, and leads to a [known anti-pattern](https://lukepalmer.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/haskell-antipattern-existential-typeclass/).

For instance, if we had a class as follows:

```
class Draw a where
   draw :: a -> String
```

then the type `MyList` above is isomorphic to `[String]` (or at least morally such). There is no advantage to store an unknown "drawable" object whose only method converts it to string compared to storing the string directly. Also note that Haskell is lazy, so you can "store a string which is not evaluated yet", so to speak.

Anyway, existential quantification on typeclasses can also be defined in a generic way:

```
import Data.Kind

-- Ex has the same role of "dyn" in Rust here
data Ex (c :: Type -> Constraint) where
    Ex :: c a => a -> Ex c

type MyList = [Ex Draw]
```

Comment: Also note that you'll see some older docs on existential types that use the awkward original syntax `data SomeDraw = forall a. Draw a => SD a` (Yes, the word `forall` was used for existential quantifiers). This answer uses the newer and much cleaner GADT syntax, which I highly recommend. But you should be aware that the old way exists.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo "Yes, the word forall was used for existential quantifiers" I don't think this is an accurate way of describing what it means. Isn't it more accurate to say that it's a result of (completely validly) transforming "(∃x. P(x)) -> Q" into "∀x. (P(x) -> Q)"?

Comment: When would you not need extensions on for this?

Comment: Maybe show an example of existential types actually being useful? Perhaps `Coyoneda` or `Day`?

Comment: @dfeuer GHC 9.2.1 defaults to GHC2021, in which all of the extensions that this code needs are already enabled, so it wouldn't be fair to say you need them anymore unless you also say you need ImplicitPrelude in basically every snippet everywhere.

Comment: @dfeuer I don't think those examples are related to this question which is about using existentials on typeclasses. Feel free to edit, though.